# sub setting a ff data frame using the subset.ff function in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to use the `subset.ff` function in the `ff` package?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
  104   11    3    3    1    1 1089
   63   11    2    3    9    1  734
   11    1    3    1    1    1 -609
   11    1    3    1    1    1 -609
   11    1    3    1    1    1 -609
```

Here is the code:

```
temp2a <- subset.ff(temp1,temp1$col7!="0") #temp1 is the name of the ff data frame
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `length<-.ffdf`(`*tmp*`, value = 12965531L) : not allowed to change the number of (virtual) columns of ffdf
```

I am trying to get two ff data frame subsets from the data. One where col7 is equal to 0 and one where col7 is not equal to zero. Does anyone know how to use the `subset.ff` function or another way to do what I want. I tried looking through the pdf for the `ffbase` library and all over the web but I couldn't find any examples.

Cheers again,

Lorcan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what does `temp1$col7!="0"` give you? Is it like `?subset.ffdf` states

```
an expression, ri, bit or logical ff vector that can be used to index x.
```

Probably you need to change it to `temp1$col7 != 0`

Comment: so temp2a<-subset(temp1,temp1$col7!=0) will probably work for your case

Comment: Cheers Jan for the help. Fixed the mistake. I should have used subset.ffdf as you say in the first line of your answer. I didn't know that there was a subset.ffdf version of subset.ff because the help files in R aren't great for the ff functions. You were also spot on about the temp1$col7 != 0 so thank you again for your help